# Does Android certificate expired date affect enterprise android app?

Tags: android, certificate, keystore

I have deployed enterprise android application through OTA.

It is signed by the expired Android certificate(keystone).

If it is signed by the expired certificate, is it not performed on user devices?

Is Android certificate expired date only checked by Google Play when i publish it through Google Play?

Doesn't Android OS check the certificate expired date when i install it on Android device?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what `Android certificate` you meant.
But if you mean certificate which used while generate signed apk, it won't affect any functionality with already installed app.

Comment: I mean certificate(keystore) which used while generate signed apk, Does its own expired date affect already installed app or update  it from current version to above version? Do I need to renew its own expired date?

Comment: Certificate's expire date can't affect already installed application. 
But if certicate expired, you aren't able to generate signed apk anymore.

Comment: I have tested and confirmed it on our Android Studio, Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: If my answer is correct, accept answer for another users.